# Getline from a file and another unknown issue

Tags: c++

When i run the code as is my output is:

```
This program will calculate the average of 10 test scores that you input

Number0
```

My cursor is right after the 0 and when i press enter it just displays the last line again. I know i need to change the instructions. I also know i need to use the getline command to have it display the string with a space in it but i dont know how to do that when getting input from a file. Also and more importiantly, it isnt getting the test scores from the file and it also isnt running till end of file.

Code:

```
/***************************************************/
/* Author:     Sam LaManna                         */
/* Course:     CSC 135 Lisa Frye                   */
/* Assignment: Program 4 Grade Average             */
/* Due Date:   10/10/11                            */
/* Filename:   program4.cpp                        */
/* Purpose:    Write a program that will process   */
/*             students are their grades. It will  */
/*             also read in 10 test scores and     */
/*             compute their average               */
/***************************************************/

#include <iostream>     //Basic input/output
#include <iomanip>      //Manipulators
#include <string>       //String stuff 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void instruct ();       //Function declaration for printing instructionstring studname ();
void input (ifstream &infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname);      //Function declaration for input
float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10);      //Function declaration for calculating average
void output (string studentname, float average);      //Function declaration for output



int main()
{
  float test1 = 0;              //Vars (test1 - test10) for test scores
  float test2 = 0;
  float test3 = 0;
  float test4 = 0;
  float test5 = 0;
  float test6 = 0;
  float test7 = 0;
  float test8 = 0;
  float test9 = 0;
  float test10 = 0;
  string studentname = "a";     //Define Var for storing students name
  float average = 0;            //Define var for storing average


  instruct();     //Function call to print instructions


  ifstream infile("grades.dat");

  input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname);     //Function call for scores

  while (!infile.eof())
    {
      average = aver (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10);    //Function call for average

      output (studentname, average);     //Function call for output

      cin.ignore(1);

      input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname); //Get new input
    }     //end eof

  return 0;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: instruct                                  */
/* Description: Print instructions to user.        */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void instruct()
{
  cout << "\n" << "This program will calculate the average of 10 test scores that you input. " << "\n" << "\n";
  //Prints instructions

  return;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: input                                     */
/* Description: Get input                          */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void input (ifstream& infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname)

{
  infile >> studentname;
  infile >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5 >> test6 >> test7 >> test8 >> test9 >> test10;
  infile.ignore(10, '\n');

  return;
}



/***************************************************/
/* Name: aver                                      */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/


float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10)

{
  float aver = 0;
  aver = test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5 + test6 + test7 + test8 + test9 + test10;
  aver = aver / 10;
  return aver;
}


/***************************************************/
/* Name: output                                    */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/

void output (string studentname, float average)      //Function declaration for output
{ 

  cout << studentname;

  cout << average;

  return;
}
```

Input file:

```
Number One
99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
John Doe
90 99 98 89 87 90.2 87 99 89.3 91
Clark Bar
67 77 65 65.5 66 72 78 62 61 66
Scooby Doo
78 80 77 78 73 74 75 75 76.2 69
Santa Clause
89 92.5 94 95 91 89 88 90 92 91
Jessie James
45 54 55 56 66 61 65.6 67 43 54
Clara Barton
87 88 76 75.7 80 88 83 84 85 81.2
Alex Mack
55 65 66.5 67 76 77.7 66 67.8 71 70
Ann Apolis
87 88 88 88 88 85.4 81 82 89 81
Stewart Mouse
90 92 93 94 95 96 97 97.7 98 99
Sue Sloan
88.5 67.7 88.8 99.9 90.9 89 87 78 89 88
Luke Skywalker
76.7 77.8 88.8 76.7 77 88 87 86 85 80.9
Harry Potter
80 83 84 85 86 79.4 78.5 81 80 82
Mary Poppins
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Last One
33 44 55 66 77 88 99 22 11 91
```

Comment: It looks like the problem that you have with reading the name is messing up the rest of your program.  Try using `getline(istream&,string&)` to read the name, and then review where you are at.

Comment: @msandiford, good catch, beat me to it

Comment: it says expected Primary Expression before '&' token same for ',' ')' and a second '&'

Comment: That was not a verbatim code answer, read up on how to use getline, which for the record is declared `basic_istream<char>& getline(basic_istream<char>&, string&);` which is a great way to freak out people just beginning C++

Comment: GCC's getline is defined like this: `template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc> inline basic_istream<_CharT,_Traits>& getline(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __str)`, and this is an example of why I think it's really unkind to use C++ as a teaching language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
infile >> studentname;
```

this line will get only the string value in the stream up until the first white space.
that is why the next >>(float) operations wont work - you have an invalid float value on your cursor.

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

> str - 
>   Extracts characters and stores them as a c-string (i.e. in
>   successive locations starting at location pointed by str and
>   terminated by a null-character). **Extraction ends when the next
>   character is either a valid whitespace or a null character, or if the
>   End-Of-File is reached**. The terminating null character is
>   automatically appended after the extracted characters. The extraction
>   operation can be limited to a certain number of characters (thus
>   avoiding the possibility of buffer overflow) if the field width (which
>   can be set with ios_base::width or setw) is set to a value greater
>   than zero. In this case, the extraction ends one character before the
>   count of characters extracted reaches the value of field width,
>   leaving space for the ending null character. After a call to this
>   extraction operation the value of the field width is automatically
>   reset to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution that doesn't require much rewrite you could probably just split name to first name and last name, reading both in the same way you're already reading name in.  You technically have two strings (2 names there) as it stands and they must be treated as such or you'll end up trying to read the second name into one of your floats.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the student name to be a whole line insted of just the first word you should use getline.

```
//Replace:
  infile >> studentname    
//With:
  getline( infile, studentname );
```

And for the output you can chain output just like input, and to add a space you just add in the literal for space. Also, I added a new line, with endl if you don't want that you can replace it with another space or whatever you want.

```
//Replace:
  cout << studentname;
  cout << average;     
//With:
  cout << studentname << ' ' << average << endl;
```